# Why ReactJS ReactDom.render() doesn't render HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

why this code below doesn't work?

```
ReactDOM.render( <h1>Hello</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

but this code works.

```
var elem = React.createElement('h1',{},"Hello");
ReactDOM.render( elem, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Coming back to react after long time..trying looking into the web.. didn't found it deprecated ? then why its not working?

Update: My browser console displays syntax error over here

```
 ReactDOM.render( <h1>Hello</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

UPDATE: Thanks for the help everything worked by adding the following line

```
<script type="text/babel">
```

Comment: `<h1>` is not valid JavaScript, it's JSX. So in order to run JSX, you need a compiler.

Comment: Babel is included

Comment: Works after adding <script type = "text/babel">

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is working, may be you are doing some other mistake, check this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'/>

<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render( <h1>Hello</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Comment: Hey I have added the CDN, without CDN React.createElement(...) would not have worked...

Comment: ya, are you getting any error in console or on terminal ?

Comment: yes, Updated the browser console error in the original question

Comment: because you forgot to define the `type="text/babel"` check the updated answer it will work :)

Comment: I had to add the babel in website to get this to work  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48414699/5237614