# Adding Babel to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, build, babeljs

I am new to ReactJS and I am having issues with importing babel to html. Currently the project is hosted on code pen [link to code pen](https://codepen.io/davedaw/pen/JJgvGK?editors=1010). I am trying host the project on local host and I am having hard time  importing babel to html without an error. When I import babel using script tag like `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>` the project crashes. Can you help me figure out how to import babel using script tag.

Comment: Are you willing to use `Webpack`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation), choosing the "in the browser" option:

> **Installation:**
>
> You can use [babel/babel-standalone](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone#usage) as a precompiled version of babel.
>
> **Usage**:
>
> ```html
> <div id="output"></div>
> <!-- Load Babel -->
> <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
> <!-- Your custom script here -->
> <script type="text/babel">
> const getMessage = () => "Hello World";
> document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = getMessage();
> </script>
> ```
>
> **Create .babelrc configuration file:**
>
> Great! You've configured Babel but you haven't made it actually do
>   anything. Create a [`.babelrc`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc) config in your project root and enable
>   some plugins.
>
> To start, you can use the [`env preset`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/), which enables transforms for
>   ES2015+:
>
> ```
> npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev
> ```
>
> In order to enable the preset, you have to define it in your `.babelrc` file, like this:
>
> ```
> { "presets": ["env"] }
> ```

Note that using Babel this way has a really limited use case. I'd suggest you to use at least the [Babel CLI](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli) to transform your code. Or, even better, use a build tool like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) to run Babel each time your code changes.

Also, **I'd suggest you to look at [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)**. It's a React app initializer built by the React teamp that makes all the setup for you (including Babel and Webpack configurations).

Answer (score 1):

Pen settings > Quick add > add React & ReactDOM > Javascript Preprocessor > add Babel. You should be fine with this.

[image]

Comment: I know about that. I am changing my host from codepen to local machine which means I can add babel just like your suggestion